# Trying to add an additional title animation to my jquery slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

So I downloaded a slideshow for my home page. It comes with 2 animated text titles (H2 and H3) that slide in from the left of the screen to center. I am now trying to add an additional line of text (H4) that should slide in from the right... with a few seconds delay.

I already edited the webpage and .css file accordingly, but the javascript I am not too sure I know exactly what to do, and I don't wanna mess it up all together.

I will paste here part of the js file where the title animation is being handled (if necessary I also stick the whole file at the bottom of this post).

```
        // titles animation
            $nextSlide.find('div.ei-title > h2')
                  .css( 'margin-right', 50 + 'px' )
                  .stop()
                  .delay( this.options.speed * this.options.titlesFactor )
                  .animate({ marginRight : 0 + 'px', opacity : 1 },  
            this.options.titlespeed, this.options.titleeasing )
                  .end()
                  .find('div.ei-title > h3')
                  .css( 'margin-right', -50 + 'px' )
                  .stop()
                  .delay( this.options.speed * this.options.titlesFactor )
                  .animate({ marginRight : 0 + 'px', opacity : 1 }, 
         this.options.titlespeed, this.options.titleeasing )
```

And here's the css file (already edited to include the added text as 'H4'):

```css
.ei-slider{
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 1999px;
 height: 500px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.ei-slider-loading{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 z-index:999;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 400px;
}
.ei-slider-large{
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 position:relative;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.ei-slider-large li{
 position: absolute;
 top: 20px;
 left: 0px;
 overflow: hidden;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
.ei-slider-large li img{
 width: 100%;
}
.ei-title h4{
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 margin-right: 13%;
 top: 30%;
}

.ei-title h2, h3{
 position: absolute;
 right: 50%;
 margin-right: 13%;
 top: 30%;
}

.ei-title h2, .ei-title h3{
 text-align: right;
}

.ei-title h4 {
        text-align: left;
}

.ei-title h2{
 font-size: 40px;
 line-height: 50px;
 font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
 font-style: italic;
 color: #b5b5b5;
}
.ei-title h3{
 font-size: 20px;
 line-height: 20px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #000;
}

.ei-title h4{
 font-size: 10px;
 line-height: 20px;
 font-family: 'sans-serif'; italic;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #f0ffff;
}




/* the thumbs... */

.ei-slider-thumbs{
 height: 1px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative;
}
.ei-slider-thumbs li{
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 height: 10%;
}
.ei-slider-thumbs li.ei-slider-element{
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 position: absolute;
 height: 10%;
 z-index: 10;
 text-indent: -9000px;
 background: #000;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}
.ei-slider-thumbs li a{
 display: block;
 text-indent: -9000px;
 background: #666 ;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 cursor: pointer;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 
        0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3), 
        0px 1px 0px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
 -moz-box-shadow: 
        0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3), 
        0px 1px 0px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
 box-shadow: 
        0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3), 
        0px 1px 0px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
 -webkit-transition: background 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: background 0.2s ease;
    -o-transition: background 0.2s ease;
    -ms-transition: background 0.2s ease;
    transition: background 0.2s ease;
}
.ei-slider-thumbs li a:hover{
 background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
.ei-slider-thumbs li img{
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 10px;
 opacity: 0;
 z-index: 999;
 max-width: 100%;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
 -webkit-box-reflect: 
        below 0px -webkit-gradient(
            linear, 
            left top, 
            left bottom, 
            from(transparent), 
            color-stop(50%, transparent), 
            to(rgba(255,255,255,0.3))
            );
 -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
}
.ei-slider-thumbs li:hover img{
 opacity: -1;
 bottom: -1px;
 -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
}


@media screen and (max-width: 830px) {
 .ei-title{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  top: auto;
  bottom: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
  padding: 5px 0;
 }
 .ei-title h2, .ei-title h3, .ei-title h4 {
  text-align: center;
 }
 .ei-title h2{
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 24px;
 }
 .ei-title h3{
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
 }
 
 .ei-title h4{
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
 }
}
```

And the html/js code on the webpage:

```html
 <div class="wrapper">
                <div id="ei-slider" class="ei-slider">
                    <ul class="ei-slider-large">
      <li>
                            <img src="uploads/2016/01/slider-3.jpg" alt="image01">
                            <div class="ei-title">
                                <h2>High end Management Tools</h2>
                                <h3>Available at your fingertips!</h3>
                                <h4>With the available technologies, we provide the methods and tools that will help society to excel to new heights</h4>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <img src="uploads/2016/01/about-1.jpg" alt="image02" />
                            <div class="ei-title">
                                <h2>Enterprises, Administration Managers</h2>
                                <h3>Improve your Performance!</h3>
                                <h4>Regardless of your position, we have the solutions for all levels of professionals, and students alike.... </h4>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <img src="uploads/2016/01/home-parallax.jpg" alt="image03" />
                            <div class="ei-title">
                                <h2>Stunning Solutions</h2>
                                <h3>For Remarkable results!</h3>
                                <h4>We are bringing today's technology to assist the traditional family with promising results.</h4>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        
                    </ul><!-- ei-slider-large -->

 </div><!-- ei-slider -->
           
        </div><!-- wrapper -->
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.eislideshow.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#ei-slider').eislideshow({
    animation   : 'center',
    autoplay   : true,
    slideshow_interval : 6000,
    titlesFactor  : 0
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Oh, and finally, the entire javascript file:

```js
 
 
 (function( window, $, undefined ) {
  
  /*
  * smartresize: debounced resize event for jQuery
  *
  * latest version and complete README available on Github:
  * https://github.com/louisremi/jquery.smartresize.js
  *
  * Copyright 2011 @louis_remi
  * Licensed under the MIT license.
  */
 
  var $event = $.event, resizeTimeout;
 
  $event.special.smartresize  = {
   setup: function() {
    $(this).bind( "resize", $event.special.smartresize.handler );
   },
   teardown: function() {
    $(this).unbind( "resize", $event.special.smartresize.handler );
   },
   handler: function( event, execAsap ) {
    // Save the context
    var context = this,
     args  = arguments;
 
    // set correct event type
    event.type = "smartresize";
 
    if ( resizeTimeout ) { clearTimeout( resizeTimeout ); }
    resizeTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
     jQuery.event.handle.apply( context, args );
    }, execAsap === "execAsap"? 0 : 100 );
   }
  };
 
  $.fn.smartresize    = function( fn ) {
   return fn ? this.bind( "smartresize", fn ) : this.trigger( "smartresize", ["execAsap"] );
  };
  
  $.Slideshow     = function( options, element ) {
  
   this.$el   = $( element );
   
   /***** images ****/
   
   // list of image items
   this.$list   = this.$el.find('ul.ei-slider-large');
   // image items
   this.$imgItems  = this.$list.children('li');
   // total number of items
   this.itemsCount  = this.$imgItems.length;
   // images
   this.$images  = this.$imgItems.find('img:first');
   
   /***** thumbs ****/
   
   // thumbs wrapper
   this.$sliderthumbs = this.$el.find('ul.ei-slider-thumbs').hide();
   // slider elements
   this.$sliderElems = this.$sliderthumbs.children('li');
   // sliding div
   this.$sliderElem = this.$sliderthumbs.children('li.ei-slider-element');
   // thumbs
   this.$thumbs  = this.$sliderElems.not('.ei-slider-element');
   
   // initialize slideshow
   this._init( options );
   
  };
  
  $.Slideshow.defaults   = {
   // animation types:
   // "sides" : new slides will slide in from left / right
   // "center": new slides will appear in the center
   animation   : 'sides', // sides || center
   // if true the slider will automatically slide, and it will only stop if the user clicks on a thumb
   autoplay   : false,
   // interval for the slideshow
   slideshow_interval : 3000,
   // speed for the sliding animation
   speed   : 1000,
   // easing for the sliding animation
   easing   : '',
   // percentage of speed for the titles animation. Speed will be speed * titlesFactor
   titlesFactor  : 0.60,
   // titles animation speed
   titlespeed   : 900,
   // titles animation easing
   titleeasing   : '',
   // maximum width for the thumbs in pixels
   thumbMaxWidth  : 150
     };
  
  $.Slideshow.prototype   = {
   _init     : function( options ) {
    
    this.options   = $.extend( true, {}, $.Slideshow.defaults, options );
    
    // set the opacity of the title elements and the image items
    this.$imgItems.css( 'opacity', 0 );
    this.$imgItems.find('div.ei-title > *').css( 'opacity', 0 );
    
    // index of current visible slider
    this.current  = 0;
    
    var _self   = this;
    
    // preload images
    // add loading status
    this.$loading  = $('<div class="ei-slider-loading">Loading</div>').prependTo( _self.$el );
    
    $.when( this._preloadImages() ).done( function() {
     
     // hide loading status
     _self.$loading.hide();
     
     // calculate size and position for each image
     _self._setImagesSize();
     
     // configure thumbs container
     _self._initThumbs();
     
     // show first
     _self.$imgItems.eq( _self.current ).css({
      'opacity'  : 1,
      'z-index' : 10
     }).show().find('div.ei-title > *').css( 'opacity', 1 );
     
     // if autoplay is true
     if( _self.options.autoplay ) {
     
      _self._startSlideshow();
     
     }
     
     // initialize the events
     _self._initEvents();
    
    });
    
   },
   _preloadImages  : function() {
    
    // preloads all the large images
    
    var _self = this,
     loaded = 0;
    
    return $.Deferred(
    
     function(dfd) {
    
      _self.$images.each( function( i ) {
       
       $('<img/>').load( function() {
       
        if( ++loaded === _self.itemsCount ) {
        
         dfd.resolve();
         
        }
       
       }).attr( 'src', $(this).attr('src') );
      
      });
      
     }
     
    ).promise();
    
   },
   _setImagesSize  : function() {
    
    // save ei-slider's width
    this.elWidth = this.$el.width();
    
    var _self = this;
    
    this.$images.each( function( i ) {
     
     var $img = $(this);
      imgDim = _self._getImageDim( $img.attr('src') );
      
     $img.css({
      width  : imgDim.width,
      height  : imgDim.height,
      marginLeft : imgDim.left,
      marginTop : imgDim.top
     });
     
    });
   
   },
   _getImageDim  : function( src ) {
    
    var $img    = new Image();
        
    $img.src    = src;
      
    var c_w  = this.elWidth,
     c_h  = this.$el.height(),
     r_w  = c_h / c_w,
     
     i_w  = $img.width,
     i_h  = $img.height,
     r_i  = i_h / i_w,
     new_w, new_h, new_left, new_top;
      
    if( r_w > r_i ) {
     
     new_h = c_h;
     new_w = c_h / r_i;
    
    }
    else {
    
     new_h = c_w * r_i;
     new_w = c_w;
    
    }
      
    return {
     width : new_w,
     height : new_h,
     left : ( c_w - new_w ) / 2,
     top  : ( c_h - new_h ) / 2
    };
   
   },
   _initThumbs   : function() {
   
    // set the max-width of the slider elements to the one set in the plugin's options
    // also, the width of each slider element will be 100% / total number of elements
    this.$sliderElems.css({
     'max-width' : this.options.thumbMaxWidth + 'px',
     'width'  : 100 / this.itemsCount + '%'
    });
    
    // set the max-width of the slider and show it
    this.$sliderthumbs.css( 'max-width', this.options.thumbMaxWidth * this.itemsCount + 'px' ).show();
    
   },
   _startSlideshow  : function() {
   
    var _self = this;
    
    this.slideshow = setTimeout( function() {
     
     var pos;
     
     ( _self.current === _self.itemsCount - 1 ) ? pos = 0 : pos = _self.current + 1;
     
     _self._slideTo( pos );
     
     if( _self.options.autoplay ) {
     
      _self._startSlideshow();
     
     }
   
    }, this.options.slideshow_interval);
   
   },
   // shows the clicked thumb's slide
   _slideTo   : function( pos ) {
    
    // return if clicking the same element or if currently animating
    if( pos === this.current || this.isAnimating )
     return false;
    
    this.isAnimating = true;
    
    var $currentSlide = this.$imgItems.eq( this.current ),
     $nextSlide  = this.$imgItems.eq( pos ),
     _self   = this,
     
     preCSS   = {zIndex : 10},
     animCSS   = {opacity : 1};
    
    // new slide will slide in from left or right side
    if( this.options.animation === 'sides' ) {
     
     preCSS.left  = ( pos > this.current ) ? -1 * this.elWidth : this.elWidth;
     animCSS.left = 0;
    
    } 
    
    // titles animation
    $nextSlide.find('div.ei-title > h2')
        .css( 'margin-right', 50 + 'px' )
        .stop()
        .delay( this.options.speed * this.options.titlesFactor )
        .animate({ marginRight : 0 + 'px', opacity : 1 }, this.options.titlespeed, this.options.titleeasing )
        .end()
        .find('div.ei-title > h3')
        .css( 'margin-right', -50 + 'px' )
        .stop()
        .delay( this.options.speed * this.options.titlesFactor )
        .animate({ marginRight : 0 + 'px', opacity : 1 }, this.options.titlespeed, this.options.titleeasing )
    
    $.when(
     
     // fade out current titles
     $currentSlide.css( 'z-index' , 1 ).find('div.ei-title > *').stop().fadeOut( this.options.speed / 2, function() {
      // reset style
      $(this).show().css( 'opacity', 0 ); 
     }),
     
     // animate next slide in
     $nextSlide.css( preCSS ).stop().animate( animCSS, this.options.speed, this.options.easing ),
     
     // "sliding div" moves to new position
     this.$sliderElem.stop().animate({
      left : this.$thumbs.eq( pos ).position().left
     }, this.options.speed )
     
    ).done( function() {
     
     // reset values
     $currentSlide.css( 'opacity' , 0 ).find('div.ei-title > *').css( 'opacity', 0 );
      _self.current = pos;
      _self.isAnimating  = false;
     
     });
     
   },
   _initEvents   : function() {
    
    var _self = this;
    
    // window resize
    $(window).on( 'smartresize.eislideshow', function( event ) {
     
     // resize the images
     _self._setImagesSize();
    
     // reset position of thumbs sliding div
     _self.$sliderElem.css( 'left', _self.$thumbs.eq( _self.current ).position().left );
    
    });
    
    // click the thumbs
    this.$thumbs.on( 'click.eislideshow', function( event ) {
     
     if( _self.options.autoplay ) {
     
      clearTimeout( _self.slideshow );
      _self.options.autoplay = false;
     
     }
     
     var $thumb = $(this),
      idx  = $thumb.index() - 1; // exclude sliding div
      
     _self._slideTo( idx );
     
     return false;
    
    });
    
   }
  };
  
  var logError     = function( message ) {
   
   if ( this.console ) {
    
    console.error( message );
    
   }
   
  };
  
  $.fn.eislideshow   = function( options ) {
  
   if ( typeof options === 'string' ) {
   
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 );
 
    this.each(function() {
    
     var instance = $.data( this, 'eislideshow' );
     
     if ( !instance ) {
      logError( "cannot call methods on eislideshow prior to initialization; " +
      "attempted to call method '" + options + "'" );
      return;
     }
     
     if ( !$.isFunction( instance[options] ) || options.charAt(0) === "_" ) {
      logError( "no such method '" + options + "' for eislideshow instance" );
      return;
     }
     
     instance[ options ].apply( instance, args );
    
    });
   
   } 
   else {
   
    this.each(function() {
    
     var instance = $.data( this, 'eislideshow' );
     if ( !instance ) {
      $.data( this, 'eislideshow', new $.Slideshow( options, this ) );
     }
    
    });
   
   }
   
   return this;
   
  };
  
 })( window, jQuery );
```

[My slider in action](http://examscan.us/sb/frontslider.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery code of your plugin, the first snipped you attached, is looking for each element (`h2` and `h3`) and animating them one after the other.

Just add the same code for the `h4` afterwards, and apply any changes you want to the pixel values.

```
        // titles animation
        $nextSlide.find('div.ei-title > h2')
              .css( 'margin-right', 50 + 'px' )
              .stop()
              .delay( this.options.speed * this.options.titlesFactor )
              .animate({ marginRight : 0 + 'px', opacity : 1 },  
        this.options.titlespeed, this.options.titleeasing )
              .end()
              .find('div.ei-title > h3')
              .css( 'margin-right', -50 + 'px' )
              .stop()
              .delay( this.options.speed * this.options.titlesFactor )
              .animate({ marginRight : 0 + 'px', opacity : 1 }, 
     this.options.titlespeed, this.options.titleeasing )
              .end()
              .find('div.ei-title > h4')
              .css( 'margin-right', -150 + 'px' )
              .stop()
              .delay( this.options.speed * this.options.titlesFactor )
              .animate({ marginRight : 0 + 'px', opacity : 1 }, 
     this.options.titlespeed, this.options.titleeasing )
```

As you can see, I told it to set `margin-right` to -150px, to apply the same difference between `h3` and `h4` as there is between `h2` and `h3`, but you can choose the value that suits your needs best.

Comment: Thank you johnny. I did just as you suggested, and it now shows up alright on the slide screen. There is however no sliding effect for the new title... And that is of essence here...

Comment: I first thought it's because the title is too long, so I broke it into H4 and H5, but still nothing going on... the text just sits there as the slide comes up.. I'm adding a link to my post so you can see what I mean

Comment: All resolved! I played around with 'px' settings untill I got it to work properly! Thanks again.

Comment: Precisely. If you look closely, jQuery animates (that's the keyword here) between the value set in the `.css` line and the value set in the `.animate` line. Glad it worked for you!

Comment: Thank you so much Johnny, the slideshow is slowly coming togther thanks to your help. I wish I can pay you back somehow...

Comment: But since you are familiar already with the object, maybe you know how I can adjust the slide images so the are aligned and positioned to the center of the page. It is so annoying right now, as in screens with lower res. the image drift to the left...